# Swap byte 2 and 4 in a 32 bit integer

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I had this interview question -

> Swap byte `2` and byte `4` within an integer sequence.
>   Integer is a `4` byte wide i.e. 32 bits

My approach was to use `char *pointer` and a `temp char` to swap the bytes.
For clarity I have broken the steps otherwise an character array can be considered.

```
unsigned char *b2, *b4, tmpc;
int n = 0xABCD; ///expected output 0xADCB
b2 = &n;   b2++;  
b4 = &n;   b4 +=3;
///swap the values;
tmpc = *b2;
*b2 = *b4;
*b4 = tmpc;
```

Any other methods?

Comment: This is a good method to use!

Comment: I'd probably use logical AND/OR/shift stuff.

Comment: @nurdglaw no information so far. the interviewer didn't seem impressed.

Comment: @czarx Perhaps they don't like aliasing through incompatible pointer types.

Comment: Perhaps they were hoping you would mention endianness. Which so far none of the answers has mentioned either.

Comment: @Oktalist -- Of course, how you deal with endianness depends on how you define the byte numbering -- in-storage or in-register?  If it's defined in-storage the storage-based schemes are insensitive to endianness.  If it's defined in-register then the shift/mask schemes are insensitive.

Comment: so the other method that you could think to use would be a union, but alignment issues make that non-portable

Comment: thanks for providing wonderful solutions by hotlicks and emilsit.
Also pointing out new views about endianess and alignment issue which i had not thought.
And sorry for bad example of ABCD but it looks easier on eyes :)

Comment: `0xABCD -> 0xADCB` is a nybble exchange, not a byte exchange, and the code given will not implement that.

Comment: you won't get the desired output with this code.

Comment: I think this method will swap AB and CD. Because the char pointer addresses AB and when you increment it, it will address CD. So when the swap is done the result is CDAB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int someInt = 0x12345678;

int byte2 = someInt & 0x00FF0000;
int byte4 = someInt & 0x000000FF;
int newInt = (someInt & 0xFF00FF00) | (byte2 >> 16) | (byte4 << 16);
```

To avoid any concerns about sign extension:

```
int someInt = 0x12345678;
int newInt = (someInt & 0xFF00FF00) | ((someInt >> 16) & 0x000000FF) | ((someInt << 16) & 0x00FF0000);
```

(Or, to really impress them, you could use the [triple XOR technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm).)

Just for fun (probably a tupo somewhere):

```
int newInt = someInt ^ ((someInt >> 16) & 0x000000FF);
newInt = newInt ^ ((newInt << 16) & 0x00FF0000);
newInt = newInt ^ ((newInt >> 16) & 0x000000FF);
```

(Actually, I just tested it and it works!)

Comment: Do you have to worry about sign extension if the input is negative?

Comment: @EmilSit - that depends on the language.  My C is a little rusty.

Comment: XOR technique it's a very nice technique, but fail when dealing with values that can be zero. A little be dangerous :)

Comment: @Kira -- Not true.  If you feel it's true show us a credible reference that states that.

Comment: @HotLicks http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/182037/is-this-xor-value-swap-algorithm-still-in-use-or-useful

Comment: _When using xorswap there's a danger of supplying same variable as both arguments to the function which zeroes out the said variable due to it being xor'd with itself which turns all the bits to zero._

Comment: @Kira -- Read that again -- it says that if you supply the same address for both variables (ie, really only have one variable and swap with itself) you end up with zero, not that if you start with zero the swap fails.

Comment: @HotLicks yes if you start with zero the swap won't fail, grammar mistake, I apologize. What I meant was, _Fail when dealing with values that can **result** in zero after XOR, ie. same values_ . SO don't let me edit my comments after a period of time :S. Still I made my point clear, it's a little dangerous to use the XOR method... Two variables can have the same value, this not only applies when swapping a variable with itself.

Comment: @Kira - No, will not fail in that case either.  Try it with a toy example.

Answer (score 4):

You can mask out the bytes you want and shift them around. Something like this:

```
unsigned int swap(unsigned int n) {
  unsigned int b2 = (0x0000FF00 & n);
  unsigned int b4 = (0xFF000000 & n);
  n ^= b2 | b4;                 // Clear the second and fourth bytes
  n |= (b2 << 16) | (b4 >> 16); // Swap and write them.
  return n;
}
```

This assumes that the "first" byte is the lowest order byte (even if in memory it may be stored [big-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)).

Also it uses unsigned ints everywhere to avoid right shifting introducing extra 1s due to [sign extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift).

Comment: Depends on whether you count from the bottom or the top.  That is not specified in the problem statement.

Answer (score 2):

What about unions?

```
int main(void)
{
    char  tmp;
    union {int n; char ary[4]; } un;

    un.n = 0xABCDEF00;
    tmp = un.ary[3];
    un.ary[3] = un.ary[1];
    un.ary[1] = tmp;
    printf("0x%.2X\n", un.n);
}
```

**in**  > 0xABCDEF00

**out**>0xEFCDAB00

Please don't forget to check endianess. this only work for little endian, but should not be hard to make it portable.